# Property of compact set K contained in an open set G

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, compactness

I'm trying to show that if $G$ is an open set and $K$ is a compact set with $K \subset G$, show that there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\{x: \textrm{dist}(x, K) < \delta \} \subset G$.

My current attempt involves using a proof by contradiction. Letting $\delta = 1/n$ we can generate a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of points that are not in $G$. I think there should be way to show that this sequence converges to a point in $K$, leading to a contradiction, but I'm not entirely sure how to proceed.

Comment: If you look at a single point $p\in K$. Then, because $p\in G$, there is a $\delta_p>0$ such that the open ball $\{x:\ \operatorname{dist}(x,p)<\delta_p\}\subset G$. Varying $p$ you get many open balls, perhaps infinitely many. But they cover $K$. Since $K$ is compact, then you can choose finitely many of those balls that still cover $K$.

Comment: @user647486 Just to make sure I understand correctly, this follows directly from a set $A$ being open if and only if there is an $\epsilon >0$ such that $B(x;\epsilon) \subset A $ for every $x \in A$?

Comment: Yes. And the last sentence from the definition of compactness or, depending on which are you using as the definition, their open cover property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d$ be the metric. Assume $K\ne \emptyset.$

For each $y\in K$ let $r_y>0$ such that the open ball $B_d(y,r_y)$ is a subset of $G.$

Now $\{B_d(y,r_y/3):y\in K\}$ is an open cover of $K,$ and $K$ is compact, so there exists a non-empty  finite $L\subset K$ such that $\{B_d(y,r_y/3):y\in L\}$ is a cover of $K.$

Let $\delta=\min \{r_y/3:y\in L\}.$

Now consider any $x$ whose distance from $K$ is at most $\delta.$   There exists $x'\in K$ with $d(x,x')< 3\delta /2$  and for this $x'$ there exists $y\in L$ such that $x'\in B_d(y,r_y/3).$ So  $d(x',y)<r_y/3.$  So we have  $$d(x,y)\le d(x,x')+d(x',y)\le$$ $$\le 3\delta /2+d(x',y)<$$ $$<3\delta /2+r_y/3\le$$ $$\le 3(r_y/3)/2+r_y/3<r_y.$$   So $x\in B_d(y,r_y)\subset G.$

Remark:  If $K$ is non-empty and compact and the distance from $x$ to $K$ is at most  $\delta$ then there exists $x'\in K$ with $d(x,x')\le \delta,$ but we do not need that in this Q.

Comment: Remark: The set of points whose distance to $K$ is at most $\delta$ is a closed set but not necessarily a compact set.